# Validation error message without brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my view, I want to show an error message for each field of my form, below each form field. So Im doing something like this:

```
<% if @event.errors.full_message(:date,  @event.errors[:date]) %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <%= @event.errors.full_message(:date,  @event.errors[:date]) %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

But the message is coming with brackets and the name of the attribute. I don't want to do an `each` at the top of the form to show all error messages at the same time. I want to show each error for each input on the form. How do I do that, without brackets and the name of the attribute on the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets `[]` to retrieve related errors for a field:

In your case:

```
<% if @event.errors[:date] %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      <%= @event.errors[:date].join('. ') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That worked @Alex Kojin. But why the use of **.join('. ')** removes the brackets of the message?

Comment: The `full_messages` method returns an array of messages; the brackets are the array object being printed out. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages

Comment: @churros `@event.errors[:date]` returns an array. `join` method will join array items to a string.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kojin!

Answer (score 1):

`@event.errors` and is an instance of `ActiveModel::Errors`, which allows you to use `[]` to retrieve errors for an attribute. You can also use `get` in the same way, e.g. `@event.errors.get(:some_attribute)`.

`@event.errors[:some_attribute]` returns an array of errors on the attribute passed. If you want the full messages, you can use `@event.errors.full_messages_for(:some_attribute)`, which will also return an array.

Your view should check for errors on the attribute like this:

```
@event.errors.has_key?(:some_attribute)
```

And you should either iterate over the errors to display them one by one:

```
@event.errors[:some_attribute].each do |error| 
  content_tag :span, error, class: 'error'
end
```

Or join them into a single string or sentence:

```
@event.errors[:some_attribute].to_sentence
```

Or show just the first/last of them:

```
@event.errors[:some_attribute].first
```

Comment: `@event.errors.has_key?(:some_attribute)` is better than `<% if @event.errors[:some_attribute] %>`?

Comment: @churros Only one of those works. ;) An empty array is truthy.

Comment: Thanks @coreyward!